# How do I use Thrift's C# THttpHandler?

Tags: c#, http, thrift

I want to write a C# Thrift service that will be consumed by a Silverlight client and need to make use of THttpClient provided in the Thrift C# source code.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to use it?  I couldn't find any tutorials or examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog with an example using the THttpHandler:

http://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/thrift-over-http-with-iis/